# Convert Double to Single without loss of precision in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, cuda, double

I don't think this is possible, hence I decided to ask here to see as googling around hasn't returned any results that hint that I can do so.

Especially after reading this:

[Can doubles be used to represent a 64 bit number without loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789408/can-doubles-be-used-to-represent-a-64-bit-number-without-loss-of-precision)

Though my numbers can be held in 32bit as the example below shows.

But is there any way in MATLAB to convert a double precision value to single without loosing information?

e.g. in MATLAB

```
> a = 103364148
a =
   103364148
> single(a)
ans =
   103364144
```

Or maybe there is another way in another language, e.g. Python?

I'm working with GPUMat where I can only use GPUSingle, so I'm trying to find a way to work with stuff that is double to MATLAB in single to the GPU.

Thanks,

Comment: Double is larger than Single. Of course you're going to lose precision, unless you happen to be in the range the two share. This question sounds like "how can I put up to thirty characters into a string of length 15"?

Comment: Yes, you can hold your number in 32 bits as your example shows, but it doesn't come out the same number.

Comment: But I thought that `103364148` is in that range? Since 32-bit is `− 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`?

Comment: @robert so is there a way to make it come out the same number then? Thanks.

Comment: A single int has 32 bits to store the number, so yes, you could fit it in that range.  A single float has 23 bits to store the number, 1 bit to store the sign, and 8 bits to store the exponent.  Matlab uses floats and doubles, not ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single can hold integer numbers up to 2^24 (16,777,216) without loss of precision - some bits are required for the sign and the exponent .

In other words, no, there is no way that you can make a number larger than 2^24 fit into a single without error (note that it can hold some larger numbers, as long as they can be written as the product of a number smaller 2^24 and some power of 2).

However, are you sure you need that kind of precision for your calculations? As long as all your integers are less than 2^24, you should be fine.

Comment: I don't hence, I'm trying to convert it from double to single, since all the numbers in the array are less than 10 million or so, without signs and without decimals, just integers.

Comment: @eWizardII: Well, then it sounds like this is your answer. If you only have integer values less than 2^24, you can convert them back and forth without loss of precision using the functions [SINGLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/single.html) and [DOUBLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/double.html).

Comment: @gnovice So why then in the example above does that not work? If you use `double(103364144)` you still get `103364144` Thanks

Comment: @eWizardII: Because 103,364,144 is much more than 2^24 (i.e. 16,777,216, the maximum range of integers singles can effectively cover). It's easier to see with the commas. ;) Doubles, however, can hold all integers up to 2^53.

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks for the support. I'll add commas for you Americans :)

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing these kinds of experiments, you should turn on

```
format long
```

so you can see more decimal values.  For example,

```
>> pi     
ans =
    3.1416
>> format long
>> ans
ans =
   3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern are integers, you could use int32 instead

Comment: Unfortunately, GPUMat does not seem to support int32.

Comment: Yea, the only problem though is since it's single precision that won't fit, see above.

Comment: Yea only GPUdouble and GUPsingle.